# Help with jQuery Plugin Development

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I was reading a couple of tutorials.  This is the link to one of them: http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html

In it, the author says,

> You'll notice that whenever I needed to select an element within the plugin, I always used obj as my context (e.g., moreLink = $('.truncate_more_link', obj)). This is necessary to constrain any selections to the current truncated element. Without setting the context like this, you will get unpredictable results.

I've read similar statements in other tutorials, but I still don't grasp what they really mean. In my mind, I understand ...

```
$('.truncate_more_link', obj)
```

... to mean, "Select elements with the .truncate_more_link class and also the element represented by the variable obj."

But it sounds like the author of the tutorial is saying "Select the .truncate_more_link class elements that are also the actual element passed into the plugin function.  Why not just do

```
$(obj)
```

instead of

```
$('.truncate_more_link', obj)
```

It seems I'm missing some understanding of scope.

Comment: That's a very outdated tutorial. You can find the latest best practices on the jQuery site: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: @Matt Ball - I've read that one too.  I made my first plugin successfully from that one, but not this second one I'm working on.  I think I get too much detail at once and I get overloaded.  Is there another up-to-date dumbed down tutorial you know of?

Comment: Just skip to the end: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Summary_and_Best_Practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass two arguments to jQuery, the second argument is used as the "context" for the first. Short version: `$('foo', bar)` means **exactly the same thing** as `$(bar).find('foo')`.

> #### *Selector Context*
>
> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the `$()` function. For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be restricted like so:
>
> ```
> $('div.foo').click(function() {
>   $('span', this).addClass('bar');
> });
> ```
>
> When the search for the span selector is restricted to the context of `this`, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional class.
>
> Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so `$('span', this)` is equivalent to `$(this).find('span')`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Comment: Yes, it is. jQuery's selectors are a superset of [CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping). So `$('.foo, .bar')` selects all elements with class `foo` and all elements with class `bar`.

Comment: Thanks, it's all starting to make sense now.  I think I was confusing the text css syntax of using commas to separate selectors with the actual comma that separates the selector from the context variable.

Comment: Yup. It doesn't sound so much like your question was about jQuery plugins as jQuery in general, so I'm going to retag your OP.